# Modify content of \footcite command and display of bibliography

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, citing, footnotes

I would like to have footnote citation of the following format:

---

[image: Needed format of footnote citation]

---

With a raised number in the text and the author (year): title, page in the footnote. The bibliography should include the rest of the information:

---

[image: Bibliography entry]

---

Here is a minimum working example, that gets close to what I need:

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @article{Amblee.2008,
        author = {Amblee, Naveen and Bui, Tung},
        year = {2008},
        title = {Can Brand Reputation Improve the Odds of Being Reviewed On-Line?},
        pages = {11--28},
        volume = {12},
        number = {3},
        issn = {1086-4415},
        journal = {International Journal of Electronic Commerce},
        doi = {10.2753/JEC1086-4415120302}
    }
    }
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,headinclude,headsepline,parskip=half]{book}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\usepackage[backend=bibtex,citestyle=verbose-ibid]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref} %Makes Table of Contents clickable

\begin{document}

    Text\footcite[See][pages 1--2]{Amblee.2008} more text

    \printbibliography

\end{document}
```

This results in the following footnote that has too much information:

---

[image]

---

and a Bibliography entry that has a `[1]` that I dont want:

---

[image]

---

How do I limit the footnote content and get rid of the numbers in the Bibliography?

Comment: The `\footcite` command belongs to `biblatex` package.

Comment: Welcome to Stackexchange btw! Your MWE is not complete. You should update your question adding at least `\usepackage{filecontents}` and everythig related to german language. `biblatex` can do what you want, but we must find the right options.

Comment: thank you for your comment that helped me advance in my problem. I edited my MWE to be more precise. The thesis I write is in English so I don't need german support, but the perfect example for the citation style I need happened to be in german.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `biblatex` style `authortitle` is close to what you want. We can make three small changes:

1. Add the date into the citation macro

   ```
   \renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
     \iffieldundef{shorthand}
       {\printnames{labelname}%
        \setunit{\addspace}%
        \printtext[parens]{\usebibmacro{date}}%
        \setunit*{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}%
        \usebibmacro{cite:title}}%
       {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}
   ```
2. Change the delimiter between name and title for `footcite` and `smartcite` contexts:

   ```
   \DeclareDelimFormat[footcite,smartcite]{nametitledelim}{\addcolon\space}
   ```
3. Change the default strings to print `page` and `pages` in full, that way you only need put the numbers into the `postnote`.

   ```
   \DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
     page = {page},
     pages = {pages},
   }
   ```

Aside: If you can use `biber` instead of `bibtex`:

```
\usepackage[style=authortitle]{biblatex}
```

## MWE

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Amblee.2008,
  author = {Amblee, Naveen and Bui, Tung},
  year = {2008},
  title = {Can Brand Reputation Improve the Odds of Being Reviewed On-Line?},
  pages = {11-28},
  volume = {12},
  number = {3},
  issn = {1086-4415},
  journal = {International Journal of Electronic Commerce},
  doi = {10.2753/JEC1086-4415120302}
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backend=bibtex, style=authortitle]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DeclareDelimFormat[footcite,smartcite]{nametitledelim}{\addcolon\space}

\renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
  \iffieldundef{shorthand}
    {\printnames{labelname}%
     \setunit{\addspace}%
     \printtext[parens]{\usebibmacro{date}}%
     \setunit*{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}%
     \usebibmacro{cite:title}}%
    {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}

% automatically use page(s) instead of p. and pp.
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
  page = {page},
  pages = {pages},
}

\begin{document}
\null\vfill
Text\footcite[See][1-2]{Amblee.2008} more text
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE output]

Comment: I took your advise and read up on the difference between bibtex and biber [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25701/bibtex-vs-biber-and-biblatex-vs-natbib). Thank you very much for your time, it works perfectly!